# Ionic build android, Error: spawn EACCES

Tags: android, macos, ionic-framework, ionic2

If I follow this steps to create a new app:

```
Rubens-MacBook-Pro:~ rlopez$ npm install -g cordova ionic
Rubens-MacBook-Pro:~ rlopez$ ionic start myApp tabs
Rubens-MacBook-Pro:~ rlopez$ cd myApp
Rubens-MacBook-Pro:myApp rlopez$  ionic platform add android@6.2.2 //6.1.x has a bug
Rubens-MacBook-Pro:myApp rlopez$  ionic build android
```

I get this output:

```
> ionic-hello-world@ ionic:build /Users/rlopez/Proyectos/sfp-concursaPy
> ionic-app-scripts build

[15:13:28]  ionic-app-scripts 1.1.4 
[15:13:28]  build dev started ... 
[15:13:28]  clean started ... 
[15:13:28]  clean finished in 3 ms 
[15:13:28]  copy started ... 
[15:13:28]  transpile started ... 
[15:13:31]  transpile finished in 2.96 s 
[15:13:31]  preprocess started ... 
[15:13:31]  preprocess finished in less than 1 ms 
[15:13:31]  webpack started ... 
[15:13:31]  copy finished in 3.17 s 
[15:13:41]  webpack finished in 9.26 s 
[15:13:41]  sass started ... 
[15:13:41]  sass finished in 897 ms 
[15:13:41]  postprocess started ... 
[15:13:41]  postprocess finished in 1 ms 
[15:13:41]  lint started ... 
[15:13:41]  build dev finished in 13.15 s 
[15:13:43]  lint finished in 2.04 s 
ANDROID_HOME=/Users/rlopez/Library/Android/sdk

JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home

Error: spawn EACCES
```

Running ionic info gives the following:

```
Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 6.5.0 
Ionic Framework Version: 3.1.1
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.3
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.3.6
ios-deploy version: 1.8.5 
ios-sim version: 5.0.13 
OS: OS X El Capitan
Node Version: v6.10.1
Xcode version: Xcode 7.3.1 Build version 7D1014
```

What am I doign wrong? Is this a bug in Ionic?

[Edit]

Running `ionic build android --verbose` gives the following output:

```
Running command: "/Applications/Android Studio 2.4 
Preview.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-3.4.1/bin/gradle" -p 
/Users/rlopez/myApp/platforms/android wrapper -b 
/Users/rlopez/myApp/platforms/android/wrapper.gradle

Error: spawn EACCES
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1018:11)
    at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:319:11)
    at Object.exports.spawn (child_process.js:378:9)
    at exports.spawn(/Users/rlopez/myApp/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/cordova-common/src/superspawn.js:134:31)
    at GradleBuilder.runGradleWrapper(/Users/rlopez/myApp/platforms/android/cordova/lib/builders/GradleBuilder.js:78:14)
    at /Users/rlopez/myApp/platforms/android/cordova/lib/builders/GradleBuilder.js:178:21
    at _fulfilled (/Users/rlopez/myApp/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:854:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/Users/rlopez/myApp/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:883:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/Users/rlopez/myApp/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:816:13)
    at /Users/rlopez/myApp/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:570:49
```

Comment: There is 0 text after the eaccess error? What if you sudo su - and then run the commands again?

Comment: That didn't work. Any ideas on how can I get some other error message? Are there any flags that I can use to print more output?

Comment: Maybe try ionic build android --verbose . If this doesnt help try to delete your hooks folder.

Comment: Thanks, it shows a stacktrace now. I'll update the question.

Comment: @misha130 It's all working fine now. There was a problem with the permissions in `/Applications/Android Studio 2.4 
Preview.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-3.4.1/bin/gradle`. You can post an anwer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Thats fine, I'd rather not answer if its something so specific. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 98):

Got the same error today. Thanks to the comments above, here is how I fixed it.

Ran:

```
cordova build android --verbose
```

and it showed me where it got the "Permission Denied" error... In my case it was:

```
Running command: /usr/libexec/java_home
Command finished with error code 0: /usr/libexec/java_home
ANDROID_HOME=/Users/mj/phonegap/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140321/sdk
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home
Running command: "/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.2.1/bin/gradle"
 -p /Users/mj/EduceMobile/app/platforms/android wrapper -b /Users/mj/EduceMobile/app/platfo
rms/android/wrapper.gradle
```

To fix, ran:

```
sudo chmod 755 /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.2.1/bin/gradle
```

...and

```
...
...
:cdvBuildDebug

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 2 mins 44.195 secs
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I got similar error after I updated my Android Studio to version 3.x. In this case, I ran the following command to fix it: `sudo chmod 755 /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-4.1/bin/gradle`. Hopefully it helps!

Comment: @CharlieAng That worked perfectly well! You should add as an actual answer rather than a comment so it can help more people.

Comment: @TheVinceble Posted it as an actual answer just now. :) Glad to hear that it works well for you.

Comment: Make sure to enclose the whole path in double quotes in case there's a whitespace in any of the directory names.

Answer (score 22):

Above solutions didn't work for me. I solved error with this command:

```sh
chmod 755 platforms/android/gradlew
```

Answer (score 11):

For those who gets similar error after updating Android Studio to version 3.x, you can run the following command to fix it:

`sudo chmod 755 /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-4.1/bin/gradle`

Hopefully it helps!

Answer (score 11):

Only for OSX
--- Go to Applications Folder from finder and Simply rename Android Studio App Package name by removing space between.

Before : **Android Studio**
After: AndroidStudio

There is no issue of permissions by default just the space was the problem.

Cheers !

Answer (score 7):

Just encountered the same issue, and I don't think it has anything to do with sudo - that command is simply missing the execute permission

```
chmod +x hooks/after_prepare/010_add_platform_class.js
```

Comment: Same. I missed setting the execute permission to one of my custom hooks

Comment: After chmod do we need to cordova rm  platform ios & add it again ? ....chmod is not working for me

Comment: You don't need rm platform.

Answer (score 6):

```
sudo chmod 755 /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-4.1/bin/gradle
```

Comment: worked like a charm. to elaborate on my situation. it seems that from the last time I ran `cordova build android` it spun up a daemon. therefore i'm guessing the last daemon was still running which didn't allow `cordova build android` to run this next time.

Answer (score 3):

Running `ionic build android --verbose` gives the following output:

```
/Applications/Android Studio 2.4 
Preview.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-3.4.1/bin/gradle -p 
/Users/rlopez/myApp/platforms/android wrapper -b 
/Users/rlopez/myApp/platforms/android/wrapper.gradle

Error: spawn EACCES
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1018:11)
    at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:319:11)
    at Object.exports.spawn (child_process.js:378:9)
    at exports.spawn(/Users/rlopez/myApp/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/cordova-common/src/superspawn.js:134:31)
    at GradleBuilder.runGradleWrapper(/Users/rlopez/myApp/platforms/android/cordova/lib/builders/GradleBuilder.js:78:14)
    at /Users/rlopez/myApp/platforms/android/cordova/lib/builders/GradleBuilder.js:178:21
    at _fulfilled (/Users/rlopez/myApp/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:854:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/Users/rlopez/myApp/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:883:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/Users/rlopez/myApp/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:816:13)
    at /Users/rlopez/myApp/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:570:49
```

Changing the permissions of `/Applications/Android Studio 2.4 Preview.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-3.4.1/bin/gradle` solves the problem.

Comment: I had to `chmod +x` to fix the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix by running the following command in Terminal

```
sudo chmod 755 "/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-4.1/bin/gradle"
```

[image]

After running that I was able to run this command successfully

```
ionic cordova build android --release
```

Answer (score 2):

My problem wasn't permissions... I couldn't quite find the origin of the problem but I did a workaround. this error was happening when I was trying to add a plugin which wasn't updated to the new files/folder system.

```
cordova platform android -v
```

it returned ->   8.0.0

What I did was:

```
cordova platform rm android
cordova platform add android@6.4.0
```

and then:

```
cordova plugin add <plugin>
```

This way the plugin installation showed no errors.. but keep in mind that after the cordova plugin add command, the android platform version automatically updated to 8.0.0 again... so I had to repeat the process in order to add another plugin with the same issue.

After repeating this process 2 times I finally got the project to run with the 2 plugins installed

Comment: Or, as ionic changes so much, it could be "ionic cordova platform add android@6.4.0"

Comment: This worked for me. I had the same problem with ios where I had to do ios@4.4.0

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, I solved it by running the command below in the app folder:

```
ionic hooks add
```

Comment: On Mac laptop got : [error] Unable to find hooks add

Answer (score 1):

I got a great solution.

This is the problem of new version of Android Studio. So downgrade this version to 2.3.3 https://developer.android.com/studio/archive.html

Answer (score 0):

Changing the permissions of

> /Applications/Android Studio App Path /Contents/gradle/gradle-*.*.*/bin/gradle

Answer (score 0):

it is a permission issue chmod cmd will help you

**step 1:** use cmd   `sudo cordova run android --verbose`

**step 2:** find  below  line it may vary on your install location:

```
/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-4.1/bin/gradle
```

**step 3:** run cmd with your location

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /Applications/Android\ Studio.app
```

**step 4:** run cmd `cordova build android`

Answer (score 0):

run the cordova command with --verbose option.  Do not prefix the command with ionic cordova.   This will tell you where the access problem is.  For me it was a problem where gradlew was installed on my system without execution privileges. Once i add execution ability to gradlew,  the eaccess error went away.

Answer (score -1):

You have to fix the 'gradle' to be executable by your system account:

`$ sudo chmod 755 /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/grad
le/gradle-<VERSION>/bin/gradle`

I had same trouble but now it's working for me.

Comment: this answer is a duplicate of several already existing answers and should probably be removed